# Input range slider step

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to create `input type="range"` to have different step values, so that it increases like 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, and so forth?

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
<input name="number" type="range" min="5" max="100" 
    value="10" step="5,10,25,50" style="width: 40%;">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "and so forth"? I truly don't know what number you'd want to come next..

Answer (score 4):

You can have it like this

```
<input type="range" step="25"></input>
```

Here you will have steps in the range of 0,25,50,75,100. Is that what you need?